# Assigning the value of a pointer at a certain index in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
struct mys {

    double d[128];
};

void my_func(int iters) { 
    int i; 

    struct mys *ptr = malloc(iters *sizeof(struct mys));


    for(i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
        ptr[i].d[0] = (double)i;
    }
    free(ptr);
}
```

What I know:

`mys` is of size `8 * 128` (size of `double` is `8`, it's an array of `128` doubles)

`*ptr` is of size `iters * (8 * 128)`

What is going on here:

```
ptr[i].d[0] = (double)i;
```

?

What I know:

```
  // ptr->d is the address of the first part of d
  // same as (*ptr).d
  // BECAUSE d IS A STRUCT

  // ptr->d[i] is the actual value. so, 0.0000
  // same as (*ptr).d[i]
```

Thanks in advance.

`ptr[i]` is the value at index `i`, so starts at `0.0000`.
`d` is not initialized, it is just the name of the member of a `struct`. How can we just `d` here?

What I think:

`*ptr` is multiple (`iters`) structs.

So, `ptr[0]` is the first `struct`, `ptr[1]` is the second `struct`, etc.

`ptr[i].d` access the `i`th struct's `d` array.

`ptr[i].d[0]` accesses the first index of the d array. So the line above sets that number to `double(i)`.

So this really only sets the first element of each struct to be `0`. Am I right?

But when `iters` is `2`, and I try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    printf("%p\n", ptr[200].d);
}
```

it still prints an address. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on here: `ptr[i].d[0] = (double)i;`?

This:

```
struct mys *ptr = malloc(iters *sizeof(struct mys));
```

allocates memory for an array of structs, called `ptr`.

This line of code:

```
ptr[i].d[0] = (double)i;
```

assigns `i` to the first cell of the array `d`, of the `i`-th struct, in the array `ptr`.

`i` is casted to `double`, because `d` is an array of doubles, and `i` is declared as `int`.

---

> when `iters` is 2, and I try: `for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) { printf("%p\n", ptr[200].d); }` it still prints an address. Why is that? Shouldn't it be out of range since `ptr` is only 2 structs?

This is definitely out of range, since arrays are 0-indexed.

However, that attempt invokes *[Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* (UB), which means that you don't know how the code is going to behave. For example, in your computer it prints an address, in my computer it might cause a segmentation fault, and so on...

Comment: Hi, so when `iters` is `2`, and I try: `for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
printf("%p\n", ptr[200].d);
}` it still prints an address. Why is that? Shouldn't it be out of range since `ptr` is only `2` `struct`s?

Comment: Hey @user2719875, this is definitely out of range, since arrays are 0-indexed. However, that attempt invokes *Undefined Behavior* (UB), which means that you don't know how the code is going to behave. For example, in your computer it prints an address, in my computer it might cause a segmentation fault, and so on...

Comment: @user2719875 no, it should be all zeroes, since the initial for-loop assigns `i` to the first element of the `i`-th struct. So, the 1st element of the first struct (`i` is equal to 0) should be equal to 0. The 1st element of the second struct (`i` is equal to 1) should be equal to 1, and so on..

Comment: This is only UB according to a severe (and probably unhelpful) reading of the standard. As a practical matter, as in an embedded application, this code will compile and run without trouble because it never dereferences the pointer.

Comment: I do not imply that your answer were unhelpful. On the contrary, your answer helps. However, it is pretty normal in certain applications to rely on a C compiler to do things beyond the remit of the C standard proper. The language is designed for this. This was my point.

Answer (score 0):

> So this really only sets the first element of each struct to be 0. Am I right?

It copies the index `i`, converted to type `double`, into the first element of each struct. Otherwise you are right.

Regarding the expression `ptr[200].d`, this is the same as `&(ptr[200])` because the array `d[]` is the sole element of a `mys` object. Because a `double` is eight bytes wide, each `mys` object occupies (8 bytes)(128) = 1 kiB. Therefore, `&(ptr[200]) == ptr + 200*1024`. The last is an address 200 kiB past the beginning of `*ptr`. Whether the address has meaning depends on whether anything meaningful is stored there.